# Moving files with bash scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, ftp

I have a bash script that watches a folder, if something is added to the folder, the script will move all contents withing the monitored folder to the defined destination.

THE ISSUE:
             - The script fails to move the files in the monitored folder to the destination folder through FileZilla (FTP). The script does work if you move the file to the monitored folder manually through a shell prompt. FTP is the only format not working properly.

Any Ideas what the issue may be?

Here is the script:

```
inotifywait -m ~/folderA/fileA -e moved_to |
    while read path action file; do
        #echo "The file '$file' appeared in directory '$path' via '$action'"
        # do something with the file
    mv ~/folderA/fileA/* "/folderB/myNewDest"
    done
```

Answer (score 6):

First, by having `inotifywait -e moved_to` only monitor for files **moved** to the target directory, you omit monitoring for files that were **written** or **overwritten** there, by, for example `Filezilla`. Add `-e modify -e create` to your command, or, unless you have a convincing reason to ignore some `inotifywait` events, discard all the `-e whatever` options.

Second, by not quoting the from files in your `mv ~/folderA/fileA/* "/folderB/myNewDest"` command you run the risk of being caught by silly filenames, e.g. `foo;rm -rf *`. I would suggest

```
find ~/folderA/fileA/ -maxdepth 0 -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0 mv --target-directory=/folderB/myNewDest --
```

which does the same thing, but more safely.